# How to store in Firestore Database after add it to firebase authentication in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have make a sign up and sign in for the application and the user can stored it to the firebase authentication but it is not stored to Firestore database.This time, I also want to store it to Firestore database. Anyone know how to store to Firestore database? Please Help, Thank you

Sign up code

```
class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  String _username, _email, _password;

  checkAuthentication() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) async {
      if (user != null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "start");

      }

    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentication();
  }

  signUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        UserCredential user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);

        if (user != null) {
          await _auth.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: _username);

          // await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"/") ;

        }
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  showError(String errormessage) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('ERROR'),
            content: Text(errormessage),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text('OK'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              //Navigator.pop(context, SignUpPage());
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()));
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.black,),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/girlsave.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Username';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Username',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.person,
                                    color: primary,
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onSaved: (input) => _username = input),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Email';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                      Icons.email,
                                      color: primary,
                                  ),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.length < 8)
                                  return 'Provide Minimum 8 Character';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.lock,
                                    color: primary,
                                  ),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                              ),
                              obscureText: true,
                              onSaved: (input) => _password = input),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                          onPressed: signUp,
                          child: Text('Sign Up',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          color: primary,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Login Code

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _email, _password;

  checkAuthentification() async {
    _auth.authStateChanges().listen((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        print(user);

        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "start");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.checkAuthentification();
  }

  login() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: _email, password: _password);
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }

  showError(String errormessage) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('ERROR'),
            content: Text(errormessage),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: Text('OK'))
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  navigateToSignUp() async {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpPage()));
  }
  navigateToForgotPassword() async {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ForgotPasswordPage()));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: (){
              //Navigator.pop(context,LoginPage());
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WelcomeScreen()));
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
              size: 20,
              color: Colors.black,),
          ),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/girlsave.png"),
                    fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Enter Email';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: 'Email',
                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                  prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.email,
                                    color: secondary,
                                  ),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                              ),
                              onSaved: (input) => _email = input),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.length < 6)
                                  return 'Provide Minimum 6 Character';
                              },
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Password',
                                labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                    Icons.lock,
                                  color: secondary,
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                              ),
                              obscureText: true,
                              onSaved: (input) => _password = input),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20),
                        RaisedButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(70, 10, 70, 10),
                          onPressed: login,
                          child: Text('LOGIN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                          color: primary,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Text('Create an Account?'),
                  onTap: navigateToSignUp,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  child: Text('Forgot Password?'),
                  onTap: navigateToForgotPassword,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Go to firebase console and enable `Firestore Database` (From sidemenu) of your project.

Add dependency [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/install)

Then improve your sign up function as below

```
  signUp() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();

      try {
        UserCredential user =
            await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);

        if (user != null) {
          await _auth.currentUser.updateProfile(displayName: _username);

          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('yourCollection').doc(user.user.uid).set({
            // Map of your data
          });

          // await Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"/") ;

        }
      } catch (e) {
        showError(e.message);
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

if you're facing permission issue then set below rules in `Rules` section

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can modify rules base on collections and documents of your database. This will help you to secure your data.

[Here](https://dev.to/jamalmoir/firestore-rules-examples-must-know-patterns-to-secure-your-data-bm1) you can learn how security rules work.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, so I map my data by adding this data: 'uid': user.uid,
            'username': _username,
            'email': _email,
            'password': _password. But it shows "The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'." how to fix? Thanks

Comment: It should be `user.user.uid` and not `user.uid`

Comment: Hi yes it can but when I run it, it still not store to Firestore but stored in firebase authentication. here is the error " W/Firestore(30133): (23.0.1) [WriteStream]: (f41aad5) Stream closed with status: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The caller does not have permission, cause=null}.
W/Firestore(30133): (23.0.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at users/vLZ4EJpWpPPvOHziAyCGkGFVgdT2: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=The caller does not have permission, cause=null} "

Comment: you need to setup rules for that collection in firebase.rules

Comment: hi, may I know where should I add the rules? and how? Thanks @blaneyneil

Comment: You will find this in `Firestore Database > Rules`

Comment: I've updated my answer, Please take a look.